# Sort dtypes by alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Imagine that we had a mock `pandas` data frame like this:

```
x = [1, 1000, 1001]
y = [200, 300, 400]
cat = ['first', 'second', 'third']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(speed = x, price = y, award = cat))
```

The data frame `df` would look like this:

```
    speed   price   award
0   1       200     first
1   1000    300     second
2   1001    400     third
```

If we want to see the columns type we execute `df.dtypes` and would give us this output:

```
speed     int64
price     int64
award    object
dtype: object
```

My question is: Is there anyway of obtaining this output but with an alphabetical order of column names? The desired output would be then something like this:

```
award    object
price     int64
speed     int64
dtype: object
```

P.D. I know how to do it first sorting the `df` so that columns appear in alphabetical order (`df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)`), and then executing `dtypes`. But would prefer to do the same in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) after [`DataFrame.dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
print (df.dtypes.sort_index())
award    object
price     int64
speed     int64
dtype: object
```

Or [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) before:

```
print (df.sort_index(axis=1).dtypes)
```